# ORACLE: "8103ORA-08103: object no longer exists" when running INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: oracle

I have an SP with following statement. When i run the INSERT INTO SELECT query separately in an SQL Developer for few records it ran perfectly but when run the same query from an SP using a job, i got "08103: object no longer exists". Could you please help me understand the reason behind this issue.

//TEMP_Result_Table is a permanent table and not GTT

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_Insert_Matching_Rec
IS
        V_SQLCODE NUMBER;
        V_SQLERRM  VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TEMP_Result_Table(BillNo,
                            Contract,
                            TIN_no,
                             Message,
                            run_time)
      SELECT
      tmp.BillNo,
      tmp.Contract,
      CASE
        WHEN ct.TIN_no IS NOT NULL THEN ct.TIN_no
          ELSE
              NULL
      END AS TIN_no,
      'PASS,
      SYSDATE
      FROM
      TEMP_Result_Table tmp
      LEFT JOIN
      tbl_Contract ct
      ON
      (
      (tmp.Contract = SUBSTR(ct.Contract, -LENGTH(tmp.Contract), LENGTH(tmp.Contract))
      OR tmp.Contract = SUBSTR(ct.Old_Contract, -LENGTH(tmp.Contract), LENGTH(tmp.Contract)))
      AND tmp.BillNo= SUBSTR(ct.Third_Party_Contract, -(LENGTH(tmp.Contract)), LENGTH(tmp.Contract))
      )
      OR
      (
            tmp.BillNo= SUBSTR(ct.Third_Party_Contract, -(LENGTH(tmp.Contract)), LENGTH(tmp.Contract))
      );

    COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN    
    ROLLBACK; 
    V_SQLCODE := SQLCODE;
    V_SQLERRM := SQLERRM;
    INSERT INTO TEMP_Result_Table(MESSAGE,RUN_TIME) VALUES( V_SQLCODE  || V_SQLERRM ,SYSDATE);
    COMMIT;
END SP_Insert_Matching_Rec;
```

Comment: The error message points to a line and column, can you show that too? And is the code you posted is not identical to what you ran, point to where in what you posted the error message points to.

Comment: @mathguy actually error is pointing to the table mentioned in Insert Into clause. INSERT INTO TEMP_Result_Table. Just to add more on this, table "TEMP_Result_Table" is a permanent table and not a GTT. And when i run this INSERT INTO SELECT query separately, i get exact results without error. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of all the tables used here. Thanks.

Comment: Is some other process performing DDL on the table while the `INSERT` is running?  That error can happen if the table is truncated or moved while the table is being read.  Use this query to see if the timing line up: `select last_ddl_time from dba_objects where object_name = 'TEMP_RESULT_TABLE';`.  I've only seen this happen when using ad-hoc queries in IDEs.  For example, if you select the first N rows, someone truncates the table, and then you try to select the next N rows.  I wouldn't think it could happen in an INSERT because the lock should stop the DDL but I could be wrong there.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jon heller for your replay. When i run query provided by you, i can see last_ddl_time is the time when my SP was running. But hard to understand which DDL had run. Also to add more on this, table "TEMP_RESULT_TABLE" is a fresh table added just for this particular task only and which we have planned to drop once done, so doubt of any other scheduler with any ddl is also not applicable in this scenario because this table is being refereed by this SP only. Could you please help me with query to get the exact last DLL that was run. Thanks

Comment: If you're lucky auditing is set up and you can find some information on the other process with `select * from dba_audit_trail where obj_name = 'TEMP_RESULT_TABLE';`.  If there's nothing in there, search through source code looking for other objects that change that table.  `select * from dba_source where lower(text) like '%temp_result_table%';`.  Finally, take a look through `select * from dba_triggers;`.  Perhaps there is some DDL trigger causing changes?  Or maybe a job in DBA_JOBS or DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS.